# gulp-live-server doesn't refresh page

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-livereload

I'm trying to use `gulp-live-server` to automatically restart my server and refresh the page whenever my code changes.

Here is the basic setup I have:

On my server.js:

```
app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
```

My gulp file:

```
gulp.task('server', function () {
   server = gls('app.js', options);
    server.start();

    // Watch for file changes
    gulp.watch(['app.js', 'app/**/*.js', 'config/**/*.js', 'components/**/*.jsx'], function() {
        server.start.bind(server)();
        server.notify.bind(server)();
    });
});
```

My server successfully does restart, but the browser does not refresh ever.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by passing the file when calling notify:

```
gulp.task('server', function () {
   server = gls('app.js', options);
    server.start();

    // Watch for file changes
    gulp.watch(['app.js', 'app/**/*.js', 'config/**/*.js', 'components/**/*.jsx'], function(file) {
        server.start.bind(server)();
        server.notify.bind(server)(file);
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe those commands are nowhere in the entire internet, but here on this least known SO post. It literally would never refresh for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: PAGE NOT REFRESHING WITH THIS SCRIPT :(